# UI freezing during file management

Tags: release-juno

I've been running Elementary 5 "Juno" since a few days and experiencing "**freezes**" on the **File Manager/GUI** when copying/moving large amounts of files (1k or more) between folders, disks or network volumes.

I have not been able to reproduce the **EXACT** steps to make it happen, but happens frequently enoguh to be an issue, since I'm trying to organize my music and video collection on my Media Center. What I'm doing:

- Open 2 instances of the file manager, one on each window, side by
  side. Instances may be local folders, an external disk or a network
  volume (SMB).
- Drag or Cut & Paste files between them.

Eventually, the file manager GUI freezes. I get the hand cursor with the + sign, the mouse stil moves. I can still alternate between apps with Alt-Tab, but **mouse clicks do not register, on any app**. I tried to let the machine in this state for up to 15 minutes to see if it would eventually "unfreeze" itself, but it didn't happen.

At this point, the only way I can get control back is by forcing a reboot/power off (holding the power button).

Is this a known issue? The machine is a Samsung R480 notebook (Core i5, 6 GB of RAM, 500 GB HDD, Nvidia GeForce 630M + Intel Integrated Graphics).

Comment: This is a known issue, work in progress. Hopefully will be fixed soon. https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/663

Comment: Thanks Hasan. Will keep an eye on it and try again on the next Elementary release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I just use the menu key to get out of the hand cursor with the + sign I know it's not the best solution but it works for me .